# When getting my source in an Azure pipeline, how do I specify submodules get checked out from a specific branch?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, git-branch, git-submodules, azure-git-deployment

We have an Azure pipeline in which we specify that submodules should be checked out when the "Get Sources" task is running ...

[image]

We are getting our source from a particular branch (named "develop").  How do I specify that I would like the named submodules to also checkout from this branch?  Right now, the submodules seem to be defaulting to the master branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure devops doesnot have the branch filter option for submodules currently. However, you can easily checkout a particular submodule branch using git commands. See below:

First, Check `Checkout submodules` option to let your pipeline check out the submodules,just like what you did in above screenshot.

[image]

Second, add a script task to run below git commands. You can manually checkout a particular branch for the submodule:

```
cd SubmoduleFolder  #go in the submodule repo folder
git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)  #check out submodule branch.
```

[image]